# Highcharts export lack of data

Tags: highcharts

I have got a highchart chart as follow:
[Chart to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBhhT.png)

As you can see on it there are values on histogram. When I am exporting it with export tool of highcharts, some values disappear as follow:
[Exported chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLmqL.png)

Is there a way to configure that I want all the values set on the export?

Thank you very much.

Regards

Damien

Comment: Maybe you miss some configuration, check this out for example: [https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic)

Comment: Does this problem also occur in JSFiddle? If so, it will be much easier if you could send me your code, so that I can also test it. Then I will be able to tell you more precisely what you can do for your config. Here you can find a basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r196jk32/